# using Estimator interface for inference with pre-trained tensorflow object detection model

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

I'm trying to load a pre-trained tensorflow object detection model from the [Tensorflow Object Detection](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection) repo as a `tf.estimator.Estimator`  and use it to make predictions.

I'm able to load the model and run inference using `Estimator.predict()`, however the output is garbage. Other methods of loading the model, e.g. as a `Predictor`, and running inference work fine.

Any help properly loading a model as an `Estimator` calling `predict()` would be much appreciated. My current code:

### Load and prepare image

```py
def load_image_into_numpy_array(image):
    (im_width, im_height) = image.size
    return np.array(list(image.getdata())).reshape((im_height, im_width, 3)).astype(np.uint8)

image_url = 'https://i.imgur.com/rRHusZq.jpg'

# Load image
response = requests.get(image_url)
image = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))

# Format original image size
im_size_orig = np.array(list(image.size) + [1])
im_size_orig = np.expand_dims(im_size_orig, axis=0)
im_size_orig = np.int32(im_size_orig)

# Resize image
image = image.resize((np.array(image.size) / 4).astype(int))

# Format image
image_np = load_image_into_numpy_array(image)
image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
image_np_expanded = np.float32(image_np_expanded)

# Stick into feature dict
x = {'image': image_np_expanded, 'true_image_shape': im_size_orig}

# Stick into input function
predict_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    x=x,
    y=None,
    shuffle=False,
    batch_size=128,
    queue_capacity=1000,
    num_epochs=1,
    num_threads=1,
)
```

Side note:

`train_and_eval_dict` also seems to contain an `input_fn` for prediction

```py
train_and_eval_dict['predict_input_fn']
```

However this actually returns a `tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver`, which I'm not sure what to do with. This could potentially be the source of my problems as there's a fair bit of pre-processing involved before the model actually sees the image.

### Load model as `Estimator`

Model downloaded from TF Model Zoo [here](http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2018_01_28.tar.gz), code to load model adapted from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/model_main.py).

```py
model_dir = './pretrained_models/tensorflow/ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2018_01_28/'
pipeline_config_path = os.path.join(model_dir, 'pipeline.config')

config = tf.estimator.RunConfig(model_dir=model_dir)

train_and_eval_dict = model_lib.create_estimator_and_inputs(
    run_config=config,
    hparams=model_hparams.create_hparams(None),
    pipeline_config_path=pipeline_config_path,
    train_steps=None,
    sample_1_of_n_eval_examples=1,
    sample_1_of_n_eval_on_train_examples=(5))

estimator = train_and_eval_dict['estimator']
```

### Run inference

```py
output_dict1 = estimator.predict(predict_input_fn)
```

This prints out some log messages, one of which is:

```
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from ./pretrained_models/tensorflow/ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2018_01_28/model.ckpt
```

So it seems like pre-trained weights are getting loaded. However results look like:

[image: Image with bad detections]

### Load same model as a `Predictor`

```py
from tensorflow.contrib import predictor

model_dir = './pretrained_models/tensorflow/ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2018_01_28'
saved_model_dir = os.path.join(model_dir, 'saved_model')
predict_fn = predictor.from_saved_model(saved_model_dir)
```

### Run inference

```py
output_dict2 = predict_fn({'inputs': image_np_expanded})
```

Results look good:

[image]

Comment: Did you manage to make it work as an Estimator ?

Comment: Nope, gave up and just used `predictor`.

Answer (score 2):

When you load the model as an estimator and from a checkpoint file, here is the restore function associated with `ssd` models. From [`ssd_meta_arch.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/meta_architectures/ssd_meta_arch.py)

```
def restore_map(self,
                  fine_tune_checkpoint_type='detection',
                  load_all_detection_checkpoint_vars=False):
    """Returns a map of variables to load from a foreign checkpoint.
    See parent class for details.
    Args:
      fine_tune_checkpoint_type: whether to restore from a full detection
        checkpoint (with compatible variable names) or to restore from a
        classification checkpoint for initialization prior to training.
        Valid values: `detection`, `classification`. Default 'detection'.
      load_all_detection_checkpoint_vars: whether to load all variables (when
         `fine_tune_checkpoint_type='detection'`). If False, only variables
         within the appropriate scopes are included. Default False.
    Returns:
      A dict mapping variable names (to load from a checkpoint) to variables in
      the model graph.
    Raises:
      ValueError: if fine_tune_checkpoint_type is neither `classification`
        nor `detection`.
    """
    if fine_tune_checkpoint_type not in ['detection', 'classification']:
      raise ValueError('Not supported fine_tune_checkpoint_type: {}'.format(
          fine_tune_checkpoint_type))

    if fine_tune_checkpoint_type == 'classification':
      return self._feature_extractor.restore_from_classification_checkpoint_fn(
          self._extract_features_scope)

    if fine_tune_checkpoint_type == 'detection':
      variables_to_restore = {}
      for variable in tf.global_variables():
        var_name = variable.op.name
        if load_all_detection_checkpoint_vars:
          variables_to_restore[var_name] = variable
        else:
          if var_name.startswith(self._extract_features_scope):
            variables_to_restore[var_name] = variable

    return variables_to_restore
```

As you can see even if the config file sets `from_detection_checkpoint: True`, only the variables in the feature extractor scope will be restored. To restore all the variables, you will have to set

```
load_all_detection_checkpoint_vars: True
```

in the config file.

So, the above situation is quite clear. When load the model as an `Estimator`, only the variables from feature extractor scope will be restored, and the predictors's scope weights are not restored, the estimator would obviously give random predictions.

When load the model as a predictor, all weights are loaded thus the predictions are reasonable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That field doesn't seem to be in the provided config files, I'll try to figure out where I can set it.

Comment: you can just added right below `from_detection_checkpoint: True`

Comment: Hmm just tried, didn't seem to do anything. `from_detection_checkpoint: True` (under which I pasted in `load_all_detection_checkpoint_vars: True`) is in the train config. Since I'm not doing any training, just predicting, I don't think it had any effect.

Comment: Then can you try removing the filtering line in the function above. Like manually set the variables to restore?

Comment: Changed the arg default from `False` to `True`, but no effect. Doesn't seem like that method is getting called when the model is loaded for prediction.

Comment: If it is only for prediction then the config file would not be needed. But since you were creating an `Estimator` by calling `model_lib.create_estimator_and_inputs`,  it will call `model_fn` and then call the `restore_map`. You can print some signs within the function to see if it actually is called.

Comment: Yeah I added a print statement to the method, it's not getting called. By the way I'm open to any other ways of loading the model as an `Estimator`, I don't care about using `model_lib.create_estimator_and_inputs`.

If you look in `model_lib.create_model_fn()` you can see that `detection_model.restore_map()` is only called when `mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN`.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. So maybe that is where the problem lies. I mean, when creating an `Estimator` without using the train mode, the weights would not be properly initialized. So maybe try train mode first and then prediction mode?

Comment: Maybe if I can somehow call `Estimator.train()` with an `input_fn` that runs for 0 epochs that would work? Because I don't actually want to change any weights.

Comment: Yes, I would try that way too. I thought about adding `restore_map` to prediction mode, but I'm not sure if it would call `restore_map` every time it makes prediction.

Comment: No luck so far, actually don't think it'll work anyway since calling `Estimator.predict()` reloads weights from the checkpoint. Very frustrating that this is so difficult.